# simplifying this block of javascript code (if)

Tags: javascript

Please help me simplifying this block of code.

any idea on how can I combine the last two if statements while preserving the functionality same.

Thanks.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) { // shortcuts
  var mapping = {
    "noctrl9": function() { // tab
      var sStart = textarea.selectionStart,
        text = textarea.value;
      textarea.value = text.substring(0, sStart) + "\t" + text.substring(textarea.selectionEnd);
      textarea.selectionEnd = sStart + 1;
    },
    66: function() { // B
      showHideStatusBar(statusBarOn ? false : true);
    },
    79: openDoc, // O
    82: newDoc, // R
    83: saveDoc, // S
    191: function() { // /
      alert("Welcome to " + appname + "!");
    }
  };
  if (e.ctrlKey && mapping[e.keyCode]) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mapping[e.keyCode]();
  }
  if (mapping["noctrl" + e.keyCode]) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mapping["noctrl" + e.keyCode]();
  }
});
```

Comment: pretty simple, just change your mapping to always include the value of e.ctrlKey ... `mapping[e.ctrlKey +":"+e.keycode]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the result of the logic in a variable, and then check separately.

```
var fn = e.ctrlKey && mapping[e.keyCode] || mapping['noctrl' + e.keyCode];
if (fn) {
  e.preventDefault();
  fn();
}
```

The assignment is equivalent to:

```
var fn;
if (e.ctrlKey && mapping[e.keyCode])
  fn = mapping[e.keyCode];
else
  fn = mapping['noctrl' + e.keyCode];
```

Or, a little shorter:

```
var fn = e.ctrlKey ? mapping[e.keyCode] : mapping['noctrl' + e.keyCode];
```

Or, while we're having fun with variations, this is a little more DRY:

```
var fn = mapping[(e.ctrlKey ? "" : "noctrl") + e.keyCode];
```

Note that the second `if` test could also be rewritten:

```
fn && (e.preventDefault(), fn());
```

That's a little too terse for me however.

Comment: It won't work, as fn would not contain a function anymore but a boolean.

Comment: @BaliBalo I'm afraid it will work, as the JavaScript `&&` and `||` operators don't work the way you think they do!

Comment: @BaliBalo try this: `var f = true && function() { alert("Hi!"); }; f();`

Comment: you're right, sorry. I didn't check it and forgot this behaviour. It would be clearer with `var fn = e.ctrlKey ? mapping[e.keyCode] : mapping['noctrl' + e.keyCode];` though.

Comment: @user2965293 you'd need the second `if` statement, as in the code in my answer.